# Autocompletion in android - for youtube search

Tags: java, android, google-api-java-client, gdata-java-client

I hope my query is quite clear from the title itself. I need to implement the auto-completion for youtube(video suggestions in a list as the user begins typing).

I need this feature for one of my Android activities.

Experts, please advise as to how to get these auto-completion list as i start typing.

Any help in this regard is well appreciated.

Looking forward.

Comment: You will need to fetch the search results as the user types in, and bind it with AutoCompleteTextView every time you fetch results.

Comment: Precisely I know that this has to be implemented using the AutoCompleteTextView.But, the fetching and binding part is what I am really unaware of. Is there any functionality that will enable us to fetch the suggestions as we type in?

Comment: ANyone out there who knows how to do this?

Comment: Well I was looking at a tutorial to do autocomplete using google places API. I imagine it would be something like this with youtube. <http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html>

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.